# Why is a "GRANT USAGE" created the first time I grant a user privileges?

Tags: mysql, database, privileges, sql-grant

I'm new to the admin side of DBMS and was setting up a new database tonight (using MySQL) when I noticed this. After granting a user a privilege for the first time, another grant is created that looks like

```
GRANT USAGE on *.* TO user IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD password
```

The documentation says that the `USAGE` privilege means "no privileges," so I'm inferring thats grants work hierarchically and perhaps a user must have some kind of privilege for all databases, so this serves as a catch all?

I also dont understand why this line has an `IDENTIFIED BY` clause in it when the grant I created does not have one (mostly because I dont understand what purpose the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause serves).

*Edit:* Sorry for not stating this originally, the grants were

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO admin_user
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON database.* TO user
```

Comment: can you please tell us the grant you've run

Answer (score 184, accepted):

As you said, in MySQL `USAGE` is synonymous with "no privileges". From the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage):

> The USAGE privilege specifier stands for "no privileges." It is used at the global level with GRANT to modify account attributes such as resource limits or SSL characteristics without affecting existing account privileges.

`USAGE` is a way to tell MySQL that an account exists without conferring any real privileges to that account. They merely have permission to *use* the MySQL server, hence `USAGE`. It corresponds to a row in the `` `mysql`.`user` `` table with no privileges set.

The `IDENTIFIED BY` clause indicates that a password is set for that user. How do we know a user is who they say they are? They *identify* themselves by sending the correct password for their account.

A user's password is one of those global level account attributes that isn't tied to a specific database or table. It also lives in the `` `mysql`.`user` `` table. If the user does not have any other privileges `ON *.*`, they are granted `USAGE ON *.*` and their password hash is displayed there. This is often a side effect of a `CREATE USER` statement. When a user is created in that way, they initially have no privileges so they are merely granted `USAGE`.

Comment: I think it is because they are allowed to authenticate. If you try with a wrong user or/and password, you can not authenticate. An user with USAGE privilege can run certain SQL commands like 'select 1+1' and 'show processlist'.

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to find the meaning of `GRANT USAGE on *.* TO` and found here. I can clarify that `GRANT USAGE on *.* TO user IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD password` will be granted when you **create** the user with the following command (`CREATE`):

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

When you **grant** privilege with `GRANT`, new privilege s will be added on top of it.

Comment: What it means "on top of it"?

Comment: it means "additionally". as in "new priviliges are added in additon to the those already  granted by `GRANT USAGE`".

Answer (score 3):

In addition mysql passwords when not using the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause, may be blank values, if non-blank, they may be encrypted. But yes `USAGE` is used to modify an account by granting simple resource limiters such as `MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR`, again this can be specified by also
using the WITH clause, in conjuction with `GRANT USAGE`(no privileges added) or `GRANT ALL`, you can also specify `GRANT USAGE` at the global level, database level, table level,etc....