# 1045 error when running mysqldump

Tags: mysql

When i am running mysqldump with user(lets say test) i am getting error message:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

Although the database and user details are correct as i am able to login. Also when i use mysqldump without passing -p then it works fine  and ask for user password.

```
mysqldump  -u test -p dbtest > dbtest.sql
Enter password:
```

I tried to pass --port, -h 127.0.0.1 as mentioned in other threads but nothing works.

Comment: does the user `test` have `LOCK_TABLES` grant? [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658996/minimum-grants-needed-by-mysqldump-for-dumping-a-full-schema-triggers-are-miss)

Comment: It is granted all the privileges, if i am not wrong "grant privileges" will include lock_tables ??

Comment: Can you show the permissions that the test user has? Are you trying to create the `mysqldump` from somewhere other than the machine where mysql server is running [Note : `localhost`]?

Comment: I am dumping the database on my own server. It has below permissions, it that what you mean ?

| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '1234'|                 

| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test`.* TO 'test'@'%'                 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126225/why-is-a-grant-usage-created-the-first-time-i-grant-a-user-privileges) - It will tell you why grant usage is not enough but you need to `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO test` to grant all privileges to the user

Comment: I granted all privileges to user "test" but still facing the same issue. What else do i need to check for?

Comment: I'm not sure then. This might help : http://www.tikalk.com/alm/solution-mysql-error-1045-access-denied-userlocalhost-breaks-openstack