# SQL Developer "usage" keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, keyword-search

[image]

I have a field in a table called "usage". (I did not create it)
In a query in SQLDeveloper the word "usage" is highlighted as if it is a keyword (like "Select")

Is "usage" a keyword is SQL? (or Oracle)
If yes, what does it do?
If no, why is it highlighted?

You can understand how difficult it has been to search for any information on this. Putting the word usage on any search returns results about to use stuff :-(

Thanks
Paul Mc

Comment: [I don't see anything here (keywords & reserved words)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm), [or here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/reservewords.htm) listing `usage` as a keyword.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlighted" - simply the color used in the editor? Or it being underlined with a wavy line (like the word "select" in thatjeffsmith's answer, on the left side of the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example I know is

```
ALTER INDEX indexname MONITORING USAGE
```

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_1010.htm#SQLRF00805)

Answer (score 2):

It's an [identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/crefsqlj18919.html), not a keyword. SQL Developer allows you to highlight them independently.

[image]

Comment: I've added an image to my question so people can see what I am on about. The field "usage" is not highlighted the same as other fields.

Comment: my answer would be correct if indeed it was used as listed originally, "usage" would be a quoted identifier :) in this context it's a keyword but not a reserved word

Answer (score 1):

According to the

[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58225/ap_keywd.htm) and the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

it's indeed a keyword, and an ANSI keyword to boot. As to its usage (pun intended), I've got no idea.

**UPDATE**

According to [this SQL grammar](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf.html#object%20privileges) by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) (I guess this is the same Jonathan Leffler, but I'm not 100% sure), it's a `GRANT`able privilege.

At least in MySQL, [this privilege seems to be used to indicate the absence of privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126225/why-is-a-grant-usage-created-the-first-time-i-grant-a-user-privileges).